# Deserializing or serializing any type of object using Jackson ObjectMapper and handling exceptions

Tags: java, generics, jackson, deserialization, jackson-databind

I currently have this code I am trying to refactor in order to allow for more possible class types (simplified with dummy code, but the gist is the same):

```
private String serializeSomething(final SomeSpecificClass something) {
    try {
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(someething);
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        throw new SomeCustomException("blah", e);
    }
}

private SomeSpecificClass deserializeSomething(final String payload) {
    try {
        return mapper.readValue(payload, SomeSpecificClass.class);
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        // do special things here
        throw new SomeCustomException("blah", e);
    }
}
```

We recently found out that we will probably have to accept other types here, not just `SomeSpecificClass`. Is there a better way of doing this without having to change everything to `Object` instead of `SomeSpecificClass`? So that we can return the right type in `deserializeSomething` (and not have to cast it after we get the return value from the caller)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start from example implementation:

```
class JsonObjectConverter {

    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public String serialiseToJson(Object value) {
        try {
            return mapper.writeValueAsString(value);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not serialise: " + value, e);
        }
    }

    public <T> T deserialiseFromJson(String json, Class<T> clazz) {
        try {
            return mapper.readValue(json, clazz);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not deserialize: " + clazz, e);
        }
    }

    public SomeSpecificClass deserialiseToSomeSpecificClass(String json) {
        return deserialiseFromJson(json, SomeSpecificClass.class);
    }
}
```

You can write two general methods: `serialiseToJson` and `deserialiseFromJson` which can serialise any type to `JSON` and deserialise `JSON` payload to given `Class`. You can implement of course some extra methods for most common and most used classes like `deserialiseToSomeSpecificClass`. You can write as many method as you need in this format: `deserialiseToXYZ`.