# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No value type configured for ObjectReader

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I am receiving `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No value type configured for ObjectReader` problem while executing below code

Jackson version is `jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar`

```
public <T> T parsingData(String body) {
  try {
    return getObjectMapper().reader().readValue(body);
  } catch (IOException ioe) {
     ioe.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Below exact Exception i'm getting in `printStackTrace` and can find the `String body` which is exposed in the exception.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No value type configured for ObjectReader
at [Source: (String)"{
     "timestamp": "2019-06-04T09:36:50.086+02:00",
     "path": "/api/check/85358/checking/246syb-f3f2-4756-91da-dae3e8ce774b/test/22462da-c4e2-45ca-bd27-246/rows/8bc3965a-ae22-4d7f-b770-262sgs24/port",
     "status": 400,
     "error": "Internal Server Error",
     "message": "[owner.firstName2:size:1:30, owner.lastName2:size:1:30]",
     "errorCode": 200000
    }
    "; line: 1, column: 1]
```

**Updated:** Could you please explain me why am i receiving this exception? Is this because that I haven't provide `Class` or `TypeReference`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parametrize response parsing in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57581859/how-do-i-parametrize-response-parsing-in-java)

Comment: Hi Michat ziober. Provided link does not address my problems since  reading the value from ObjectMapper. Here iam reading using ObjectReader.

Comment: But there is no a big difference, you just write to change it to: `getObjectMapper().readValue(body, clazz);`. You can not read object without providing `Class` or `TypeReference`. In case you want to read `JSON` without providing class you can expect `Map` or `List` - nothing more.

Comment: ok Thanks Michal, But could you tell me then why im getting this exception? is  this because i haven't provide any `Class` or `TypeReference`.? If so, but based on jackson library, code makes sense right?

Comment: please validate your json using https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No
>   value type configured for ObjectReader

Means, `Jackson` does not know which type you would like to deserialise to. It does not work because of [Type Erasure in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-erasure).

It will work when you bind a class:

```
public static <T> T parsingData(String body) throws IOException {
    return new ObjectMapper().readerFor(A.class).readValue(body);
}
```

Or with `Class` param:

```
public static <T> T parsingData(String body, Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
    return new ObjectMapper().readerFor(clazz).readValue(body);
}
```

See similar question for `readValue` method and how it could be solved: [How do I parametrize response parsing in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57581859/how-do-i-parametrize-response-parsing-in-java)

To understand `readValue` mehtod we need to take a look on [documentation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectReader.html#readValue-java.lang.String-):

> Method that binds content read from given JSON string, using **configuration** of this reader. Value return is either newly constructed, or root value that was specified with
>   withValueToUpdate(Object).

but in your code you used pure reader without any configuration.

If you do not know a type just deserialise `JSON` to `JsonNode` which is probably the most generic way:

```
JsonNode root = new ObjectMapper().readTree(json);
```