# Refactor method to use generic for deserialization

Tags: java, generics, jackson, deserialization

Here is the method that I want to refactor:

```
public static List<ComponentPOCO> parseJsonComponentFromString(String fileContents){

        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
                    .enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
                    .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
            List<ComponentPOCO> component = mapper.readValue(fileContents, new TypeReference<List<ComponentPOCO>>() {});
            return component;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I'm attempting to refactor my deserialization method to use generics to enable me to deserialize any type. I can do this just fine for objects that are not in a collection, like this:

```
public static <T> T parseProductData(String jsonData, Class<T> typeClass) throws IOException, IllegalAccessException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    T inputMessage = objectMapper.readValue(jsonData, typeClass);
    return inputMessage;
}
```

Here is an example of the data that I'm deserializing into the `ComponentPOCO` class:

```
[
      {   "artifactPathOrUrl": "http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/sample/sample.jar.zip",
        "namespace": "exampleNamespace1",
        "name": "exampleName1",
        "tenant": "exampleTenant1"
      },

      {   
        "artifactPathOrUrl": "http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/sample-calculator/sample-calculator-bundle-2.0.jar.zip",
        "namespace": "exampleNamespace1",
        "name": "exampleName2",
        "tenant": "exampleTenant1"
      },
      {   
        "artifactPathOrUrl": "http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/helloworld/helloworld.jar.zip",
        "namespace": "exampleNamespace1",
        "name": "exampleName3",
        "tenant": "exampleTenant1"
      },
      {   
        "artifactPathOrUrl": "http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/fabric-activemq/fabric-activemq-demo-7.0.2.fuse-097.jar.zip",
        "namespace": "exampleNamespace1",
        "name": "exampleName4",
        "tenant": "exampleTenant1"
      }
]
```

Here is the code of the ComponentPOCO type:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.*;
import lombok.experimental.Accessors;
import org.apache.pulsar.common.io.SinkConfig;
import org.apache.pulsar.common.io.SourceConfig;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@Setter
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Data
public class ComponentPOCO {
    @JsonProperty
    private String namespace;
    @JsonProperty
    private String tenant;
    @JsonProperty
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty
    private String type;
    @JsonProperty
    private String destinationTopicName;
    @JsonProperty
    private String artifactPathOrUrl;
    @JsonProperty
    private String className;
    @JsonProperty
    private List<String> inputs;
    @JsonProperty
    private String output;
    @JsonProperty
    private Map<String, Object> userConfig;
    @JsonProperty
    private String logTopic;
    @JsonProperty
    private Map<String, Object> configs;
    @JsonProperty
    private Integer parallelism;
    @JsonProperty
    public String sinkType;
    @JsonProperty
    private String sourceType;
    @JsonProperty
    public String runtimeFlags;
}
```

Is there a way to enable me to deserialize an entire list using generics like this?

Comment: already answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349421/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialise-an-array-of-objects#comment7431246_6349421

Answer (score 0):

You can extract all kind of interaction with `Jackson` to extra class and hide all difficulties there. `ObjectMapper` can be created and configured once. For single object you can use `readValue(String content, Class<T> valueType)` method and for collection you need to build [TypeReference](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html?is-external=true) and use `readValue(String content, TypeReference valueTypeRef)` method. Simple implementation could look like below:

```
class JsonMapper {

  private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

  public JsonMapper() {
    // configure mapper instance if required
    mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
    mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
    // etc...
  }

  public String serialise(Object value) {
    try {
      return mapper.writeValueAsString(value);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Could not generate JSON!", e);
    }
  }

  public <T> T deserialise(String payload, Class<T> expectedClass) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(payload);
    Objects.requireNonNull(expectedClass);

    try {
      return mapper.readValue(payload, expectedClass);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("JSON is not valid!", e);
    }
  }

  public <T> List<T> deserialiseList(String payload, Class<T> expectedClass) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(payload);
    Objects.requireNonNull(expectedClass);

    try {
      return mapper.readValue(payload, constructListTypeOf(expectedClass));
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("JSON is not valid!", e);
    }
  }

  private <T> CollectionType constructListTypeOf(Class<T> expectedClass) {
    return mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, expectedClass);
  }
}
```

And usage:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.CollectionType;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class JsonApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JsonMapper mapper = new JsonMapper();
    System.out.println(mapper.deserialise("{\"id\":1233}", A.class));
    System.out.println(mapper.deserialiseList("[{\"id\":4567}]", A.class));
  }
}

class A {
  private int id;

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "A{" + "id=" + id + '}';
  }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
A{id=1233}
[A{id=4567}]
```

See also:

- [How do I parametrize response parsing in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57581859/how-do-i-parametrize-response-parsing-in-java)
- [Deserializing or serializing any type of object using Jackson
  ObjectMapper and handling exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56299558/deserializing-or-serializing-any-type-of-object-using-jackson-objectmapper-and-h)