# Is passing around TypeReference<T> manually a good practise while using generics in java

Tags: java, jackson, type-conversion, json-deserialization, objectmapper

I have a method, which uses generics as follows

```
  public <T> ReturnThis<T> doSomething(Request req) {
        .
        .
     T result = ObjectMapperFactory.getMapper().readValue(req, new TypeReference<T>() {});
        .
        .
     return ReturnThis<T>;
  }
```

I do understand that there are @JsonSubTypes that can be used to explicitly let the Jackson know about type. But that is not my use case over here.

Alternatively, this could also be done

```
 public <T> ReturnThis<T> doSomething(Request req, TypeReference<T> type) {
       .
       .
    T result = ObjectMapperFactory.getMapper().readValue(req, type);
       .
       .
    return ReturnThis<T>;
 }
```

Is the below one more preferred or more safer?

Comment: It depends. Do you want it to be generic? Use second method. Altough, first method makes no sense to me because you are not specifying the generic type anywhere in the signature.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat The generic type is specified the same way as in method two.

Comment: @Tom It's redundant. It's not being used.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Both method bodies only have two lines of code each and you ignored them all? The generic type _is_ used in both version.

Comment: Actually my concern was about passing around the TypeReference vs initialising it.

Comment: @chaitra.kear As I have already mentioned, it depends on the needs.

Comment: @Tom I can't find any reason for specifying a `T`. I can use `public <SomeType> ReturnThis<SomeType>` because I already know the type. I bet some IDE will raise a warning on method number 1. I hope you understand it now.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat So you say you don't need `T`, but then create the generic type `SomeType`? I guess you meant `public ReturnThis<SomeType>`?

Comment: @Tom Yeah, that's what I mean. Sorry for the typo. But you got the point.

Comment: What could help compare the scenarios better is to understand the type inference when the method generics are in use. In the former example, the type `T` while the mapping takes place is *solely inferred* based on the context from which the method `doSomething` would be called, while in the latter the inference would also *also* be based around the `TypeReference<T>` passed down as an argument to that method.

Comment: On another note, might be that you can simplify the code in question to `public <T> T doSomething(Request req) throws IOException {
        return new ObjectMapper().readValue(
                String.valueOf(req), new TypeReference<T>() {
                });
    }` and `public <T> T doSomething(Request req, TypeReference<T> type) throws IOException {
        return new ObjectMapper().
                readValue(String.valueOf(req), type);
    }` with sample class `class Request {
    }`

Comment: Take a look at: [How do I parametrize response parsing in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57581859/how-do-i-parametrize-response-parsing-in-java), [Deserializing or serializing any type of object using Jackson ObjectMapper and handling exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56299558/deserializing-or-serializing-any-type-of-object-using-jackson-objectmapper-and-h), [Refactor method to use generic for deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57975814/refactor-method-to-use-generic-for-deserialization)